# Magento 2.3.4 UpdateItemsQty controller as well as plugin has wrong store

Tags: magento2.3, multistore, plugin, magento2.3.4, update-cart

Purpose:

- Restrict cart item quantity update when total products are more than 10. So I have created around plugin for UpdateItemQty controller which check total quantities and return error when items are more than 10.

Problem:

- Error return successfully but problem is it translate error string as per default store. I have checked current store and found that current store is not set. So website shows that I am in **en-int** store but this controller shows current store is **de-de**.

UpdateItemQty.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Ronak Chauhan 
 */

namespace MyModule\Checkout\Plugin\Controller\Cart;

use Closure;
use Exception;
use Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\UpdateItemQty as ParentClass;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\RequestQuantityProcessor;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use MyModule\Checkout\Helper\Data;

class UpdateItemQty
{
    /** @var Json */
    protected $json;

    /** @var Data */
    protected $helper;

    /** @var RequestInterface */
    protected $request;

    /** @var RequestQuantityProcessor */
    private $quantityProcessor;

    public function __construct(
        Json $json,
        Data $helper,
        RequestQuantityProcessor $quantityProcessor,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->json = $json;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->quantityProcessor = $quantityProcessor;
    }

    /**
     * @param ParentClass $subject
     * @param Closure $proceed
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function aroundExecute(ParentClass $subject, Closure $proceed)
    {
        try {
            $cartRequestData = $this->request->getParam('cart');
            $cartData = $this->quantityProcessor->process($cartRequestData);

            if (true) {
                $cartRestrictionError = __(
                    "We are happy that you like so many products! Unfortunately, %1 is the limit for number of items in your shopping cart.",
                    10
                );
                return $subject->getResponse()->representJson(
                    $this->json->serialize(
                        $this->helper->getResponseData(
                            mb_strtoupper($cartRestrictionError, 'UTF-8')
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $subject->getResponse()->representJson(
                $this->json->serialize($this->helper->getResponseData($e->getMessage()))
            );
        }
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

In above around plugin as well as Original controller I have checked current store but getting default store only.

If anyone has idea it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something when quantities are updating in cart page then please use below plugin method.

> Step 1 : Please create di.xml file under path
> Namespace/PackageName/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
        <plugin name="interceptUpdateProductToCart" type="Namespace\PackageName\Plugin\RestrictCartPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Please create RestrictCartPlugin.php under path
> Namespace/PackageName/Plugin/RestrictCartPlugin

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\PackageName\Plugin;

class RestrictCartPlugin
{
    public function aroundUpdateItems(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $subject, callable $proceed, $data)
    {
        //do your stuff here around update quantities of items
    }
}
```

Please check above way.

You can set current store programmatically as per below

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */

 protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

// now you can set your current store like

```
$this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('YOUR_STORE_ID');
```

Comment: quation updated.

Comment: Please try to set current store pro grammatically in your controller.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: you can set current store in the starting of code.

Comment: I already tried this but it's not working.